# How to display Custom colour bar into list view Adaptor in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, achartengine, android-graphview

I want to display Custom colour Bar like column (but not graph) into my custom list view of android.
I tried AchartEngine but it gives me unnecessary things like chart name x and y values plus code into Getview method of list adaptor is memory consuming.

I am looking for solution which can draw just simple colour bar into my list view item without memory and performance issue.
please Find attached Image what i want to do exactly.

[image]
this is my code for AchartEngine

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
     if( convertView == null ){
         LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lea_search_adaptor_item, parent, false);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    int[] y = { 60, 50, 55, 80,60};
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("");// i don't want title
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        series.add("Bar " + (i+1), y[i]);
    }
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("");
    mRenderer.setXTitle(""); // i don't want title
    mRenderer.setYTitle("");// i don't want title
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.GREEN);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);
    // Customize bar 1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    GraphicalView graphicalView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, null);
    layout.addView(graphicalView);
   else
     {
         viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }

        return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `I want to display Custom colour Bar like column (but not graph)`, `I tried AchartEngine`... can you elaborate more? aChartEngine is for drawing **graphs**, but you said **you don't want graphs**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I want to display 6 colour bar or right hand side of every list view Item... 6 different colour bar  and i don't want to display titles, x title , y title.

Comment: Are these coloured bars a graph or simply some coloured rectangles? Because it's not clear why do you use a graph engine if you say that you don't want graphs... You could use xml drawables or 9 patches, instead.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Any sample which explain how can i use 9 patches..

Comment: 9 patches are just png files with a 1 px border added, on each side. when you put some black pixels on these borders, you define some areas (stretchable or padding). Nice tutorial here: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: And all this beautiful features without a 3rd party library! I love 9 patches!!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein okay so according to you i have to use image view which can show 9 patch colour image and i can change heigh of image view to display colour bar into list view item?

Comment: Well, I still don't get what is your exact goal. Could you please add a picture with the desired item look for the ListView items? It doesn't have to be the real thing, a Paint or GIMP mockup will go.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein please take a look at image..I want to implement something like this..every list item content dynamic colour bar which value get changed depending on Offer of job...Picture added into main question

Comment: ...dynamic! so it's graphs! why did you say that you didn't want graphs, then? these ones are **real graphs** (even if micro-sized). No, this isn't a suitable case for 9 patches, then. a bar graph engine is needed, such as aChartEngine or ChartView. I hoped you wanted something different (maybe a **fixed** graph, like an icon and only the % changing). For speed and resources sake.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein okay i have used aChartEngine. but i don't understand how can i resize the width of column and just display 6 column.

Comment: To display 6 columns, just feed an array with 6 values. The bar sizes, I guess, is automatic (I never played with bars). Well, using aChartEngine, you can experiment other types of graphs, like the pie graph that could be a nice alternative (?)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Can you please tell me how can i stop scrolling chart in aChartEngine?

Comment: This is a **different question**. Consider posting another question on the argument, if it already doesn't exist.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i found it.. i used mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0,10,0,5});

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android i have also the same problem but in my case not any graph is showing in the listview when i used that.can u tell me how do i populate the graph like view to the listview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 mRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
 mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

For Colors

```
public static int[] COLORS_I = new int[] {Color.argb(255, 142, 142,142),Color.argb(255, 229, 77, 67),Color.argb(255, 255, 149, 0),
    Color.argb(255, 59, 153, 216),Color.argb(255, 42, 187, 155),Color.argb(255, 240, 195, 48)}; 

SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer_I = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();  
renderer_I.setColor(COLORS_I[(arraylist.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS_I.length]);  
mRenderer_I.addSeriesRenderer(renderer_I);
```

hope it helps ..

Comment: it works..it removes all the caption from graph..but i am looking for another solution which does not affect my performance.

Comment: Please take a look at picture on main question